Laravel reverb socket is not connecting
I am trying to integrate laravel reverb into a existing laravel 11 project,i started reverb server but no connection into websockets.so i tried to install reverb into fresh project it's working fine.i am not sure what is the problem,i tried to add ssl with laragon but it same,for fresh project it is working.in case need more data feel free to ask.
In developer console

In reverb console
 php artisan reverb:start --host="0.0.0.0" --port=8080 --hostname="http://sos_new_l11.test" --debug

   INFO  Starting server on 0.0.0.0:8080 (http://sos_new_l11.test).

  Pruning Stale Connections ..................................................
  Pinging Inactive Connections ...............................................
  Pruning Stale Connections ..................................................
  Pinging Inactive Connections ...............................................
  Pruning Stale Connections ..................................................
  Pinging Inactive Connections ...............................................
  Pruning Stale Connections ..................................................
  Pinging Inactive Connections ...............................................
  Pruning Stale Connections ..................................................

.env
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=sample key
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_TIMEZONE=UTC
APP_URL=http://sos_new_l11.test

APP_LOCALE=en
APP_FALLBACK_LOCALE=en
APP_FAKER_LOCALE=en_US

APP_MAINTENANCE_DRIVER=file
APP_MAINTENANCE_STORE=database

BCRYPT_ROUNDS=12

LOG_CHANNEL=stack
LOG_STACK=single
LOG_DEPRECATIONS_CHANNEL=null
LOG_LEVEL=debug

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=test_sos_db
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

SESSION_DRIVER=database
SESSION_LIFETIME=120
SESSION_ENCRYPT=false
SESSION_PATH=/
SESSION_DOMAIN=null

BROADCAST_CONNECTION=reverb
FILESYSTEM_DISK=local
QUEUE_CONNECTION=database

CACHE_STORE=database
CACHE_PREFIX=

REVERB_APP_ID=393974
REVERB_APP_KEY=bfgqzz1tpgpq7bapyxko
REVERB_APP_SECRET=hv6u8x5ijgbavlzjc7gk
REVERB_HOST="sos_new_l11.test"
REVERB_PORT=8080
REVERB_SCHEME=http

VITE_REVERB_APP_KEY="${REVERB_APP_KEY}"
VITE_REVERB_HOST="${REVERB_HOST}"
VITE_REVERB_PORT="${REVERB_PORT}"
VITE_REVERB_SCHEME="${REVERB_SCHEME}"

boostrap.js
import axios from 'axios';
window.axios = axios;

window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';

/**
 * Echo exposes an expressive API for subscribing to channels and listening
 * for events that are broadcast by Laravel. Echo and event broadcasting
 * allow your team to quickly build robust real-time web applications.
 */

import './echo';

echo.js
import Echo from 'laravel-echo';

import Pusher from 'pusher-js';
window.Pusher = Pusher;

window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'reverb',
    key: import.meta.env.VITE_REVERB_APP_KEY,
    wsHost: import.meta.env.VITE_REVERB_HOST,
    wsPort: import.meta.env.VITE_REVERB_PORT ?? 80,
    wssPort: import.meta.env.VITE_REVERB_PORT ?? 443,
    forceTLS: 'http',
    enabledTransports: ['ws', 'wss'],
});

broadcasting.php
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Broadcaster
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option controls the default broadcaster that will be used by the
    | framework when an event needs to be broadcast. You may set this to
    | any of the connections defined in the "connections" array below.
    |
    | Supported: "reverb", "pusher", "ably", "redis", "log", "null"
    |
    */

    'default' => env('BROADCAST_CONNECTION', 'null'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Broadcast Connections
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may define all of the broadcast connections that will be used
    | to broadcast events to other systems or over WebSockets. Samples of
    | each available type of connection are provided inside this array.
    |
    */

    'connections' => [

        'reverb' => [
            'driver' => 'reverb',
            'key' => env('REVERB_APP_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('REVERB_APP_SECRET'),
            'app_id' => env('REVERB_APP_ID'),
            'options' => [
                'host' => env('REVERB_HOST'),
                'port' => env('REVERB_PORT', 443),
                'scheme' => env('REVERB_SCHEME', 'https'),
                'useTLS' => env('REVERB_SCHEME', 'https') === 'https',
            ],
            'client_options' => [
                // Guzzle client options: https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html
            ],
        ],

        'pusher' => [
            'driver' => 'pusher',
            'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
            'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
            'options' => [
                'cluster' => env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'),
                'host' => env('PUSHER_HOST') ?: 'api-'.env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER', 'mt1').'.pusher.com',
                'port' => env('PUSHER_PORT', 443),
                'scheme' => env('PUSHER_SCHEME', 'https'),
                'encrypted' => true,
                'useTLS' => env('PUSHER_SCHEME', 'https') === 'https',
            ],
            'client_options' => [
                // Guzzle client options: https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html
            ],
        ],

        'ably' => [
            'driver' => 'ably',
            'key' => env('ABLY_KEY'),
        ],

        'log' => [
            'driver' => 'log',
        ],

        'null' => [
            'driver' => 'null',
        ],

    ],

];

reverb.php
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Reverb Server
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option controls the default server used by Reverb to handle
    | incoming messages as well as broadcasting message to all your
    | connected clients. At this time only "reverb" is supported.
    |
    */

    'default' => env('REVERB_SERVER', 'reverb'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Reverb Servers
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may define details for each of the supported Reverb servers.
    | Each server has its own configuration options that are defined in
    | the array below. You should ensure all the options are present.
    |
    */

    'servers' => [

        'reverb' => [
            'host' => env('REVERB_SERVER_HOST', '0.0.0.0'),
            'port' => env('REVERB_SERVER_PORT', 8080),
            'hostname' => env('REVERB_HOST'),
            'options' => [
                'tls' => [],
            ],
            'max_request_size' => env('REVERB_MAX_REQUEST_SIZE', 10_000),
            'scaling' => [
                'enabled' => env('REVERB_SCALING_ENABLED', false),
                'channel' => env('REVERB_SCALING_CHANNEL', 'reverb'),
                'server' => [
                    'url' => env('REDIS_URL'),
                    'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
                    'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', '6379'),
                    'username' => env('REDIS_USERNAME'),
                    'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD'),
                    'database' => env('REDIS_DB', '0'),
                ],
            ],
            'pulse_ingest_interval' => env('REVERB_PULSE_INGEST_INTERVAL', 15),
            'telescope_ingest_interval' => env('REVERB_TELESCOPE_INGEST_INTERVAL', 15),
        ],

    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Reverb Applications
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may define how Reverb applications are managed. If you choose
    | to use the "config" provider, you may define an array of apps which
    | your server will support, including their connection credentials.
    |
    */

    'apps' => [

        'provider' => 'config',

        'apps' => [
            [
                'key' => env('REVERB_APP_KEY'),
                'secret' => env('REVERB_APP_SECRET'),
                'app_id' => env('REVERB_APP_ID'),
                'options' => [
                    'host' => env('REVERB_HOST'),
                    'port' => env('REVERB_PORT', 443),
                    'scheme' => env('REVERB_SCHEME', 'https'),
                    'useTLS' => env('REVERB_SCHEME', 'https') === 'https',
                ],
                'allowed_origins' => ['*'],
                'ping_interval' => env('REVERB_APP_PING_INTERVAL', 60),
                'activity_timeout' => env('REVERB_APP_ACTIVITY_TIMEOUT', 30),
                'max_message_size' => env('REVERB_APP_MAX_MESSAGE_SIZE', 10_000),
            ],
        ],

    ],

];

